# Cannot login to chat when primary OpenID is Stack Exchange OpenID

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, openid, authentication

Over at Super User account, I have Stack Exchange OpenID set as my primary OpenID. I can no longer login to chat using it - I get stuck at this screen

[image]

I can repro the same using Chrome, IE9 & Firefox - there's no popup showing up asking to relogin et al. The [GlobalAuth login tests](https://chat.stackexchange.com/help) pass successfully too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was an issue with the infrastructure that's responsible for the data exchange between all the different sites in the network.

Don't ask me for details, I have *no idea at all* how that thing works.

But either way, [Kevin](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/130213/kevin-montrose) has fixed it. Some users who recently changed their data (in particular their OpenId, like in this case) may still have some issues for a short while, but it should be all good soon.

Both myself and [Sathya](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/628554#628554) can confirm it's working for us again.

Comment: "Don't ask me for details, I have no idea at all how that thing works." -- the answer is, of course, that it works *poorly*.

Comment: @KevinMontrose: I must usually be working, otherwise no-one would have noticed when it stopped :)